# DocuSign - View Form Data

Tags: docusignapi

Another company we partner with sends us new client information via DocuSign envelopes completed by those clients. I am attempting to extract the form data from the document, either via the PDF or via the DocuSign API.  The PDF only appears to have the Envelope ID embedded in it.  When I add my account as a CC recipient and try to view the form data in the DocuSign console, I receive an error message:

[image: Cannot access form data. You do not have the necessary permission to access this data.]

Additionally, I'm unable to view the form data via the DocuSign API.

```js
{
  errorCode: "USER_LACKS_PERMISSIONS",
  message: "This user lacks sufficient permissions to access this resource."
}
```

I've tried accessing via the API at:

- /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients/{recipientId}/tabs
- /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/{documentId}/fields

Questions:

1. Is there a way for a user who is not in the sender's tenant to be able to view the envelope form data?
2. Is there a way for DocuSign to embed the tab data into the PDF for extraction?
3. Is there another approach I'm not considering?

Comment: Hi @charis, Check out this support blog post to resolve: https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/DocuSign-REST-API-GET-Envelope-Form-Data-Error-This-user-lacks-sufficient-permissions-to-access-this-resource

Comment: Hi @sssurii - at the time the user did have the appropriate permissions. If something changed on the DocuSign API side to allow this now with that permission, that would be good. As this issue is long past, I'm not currently set up to check it again, and I was able to work around it with the SOAP API. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the user is cc to the envelope using the same userId and email combination that is on their account, then that user also can use the API to gain account information. (account is what you call "tenant.")

If the user is not on the envelope and you just receive the PDF some other way, then you cannot use the API to obtain information about the envelope because that is limited only to recipients of the envelope.

Comment: Apologies if I didn't state it very concisely, but that's what I meant by "When I add my account as a CC recipient and try to view the form data in the DocuSign console, I receive an error message." I'm able to get envelope properties via the API, but I cannot read the form field data either via the API nor from the web application.

Comment: how do you "add my account as a CC recipient" exactly? it's not enough to just add the email address. The name must match exactly and/or you need to specify the userId (GUID) in the recipient information.

Comment: I added that user's email as a CC recipient, and the name and email match exactly. I'm confident it was added exactly because it shows up in the web console for that user (under the manage tab).

Comment: ok, if it shows up in the web app for that user - that's a sign that user has access.
so are you still getting an error saying you don't have permission? for the exact same user?

Comment: Yes. I go into the envelope, and click More > Form Data. It works for the sending account, but not for the CC recipient.  It also doesn't work via the API method as described above.  I've noticed in the account settings that there is an option (selected in this case) named "Allow sender to download form data," but there's no recipient equivalent. It seems this is by design. I can think of reasons why, but it's inconvenient and I'm hoping there's a workaround. At this stage I'm thinking not, and we'll either have to get the partner to implement Connect on our behalf, or use an OCR solution.

Answer (score 0):

@Inbar-Gazit was kind enough to do some digging internally at DocuSign, and after a bit of back-and-forth, discovered that this is possible using the SOAP API with the RequestEnvelope and RequestEnvelopeV2 methods.  I'm unsure if there's any advantage to using one method over the other. Both also have async methods.

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-soap-api/reference/Status-and-Managing-Group/RequestEnvelope

Some quick-and-dirty C# validated that this will indeed work.  I validated this both as the sending account (which also works via REST) and the CC recipient account (which did not work via REST).

```csharp
var authString = $"<DocuSignCredentials><Username>{_userName}</Username><Password>{_password}</Password><IntegratorKey>{_apiKey}</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>";

var client = new DSAPIServiceSoapClient();

using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
{
    HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
    httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authString);
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestProperty;

    EnvelopeStatus status = client.RequestStatusEx(_envelopeId);
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Subject: " + status.Subject);

    // RequestEnvelope Method
    var envelope = client.RequestEnvelope(_envelopeId, false);
    var testTab = envelope.Tabs.FirstOrDefault(t => t.TabLabel.Contains("Test"));
    if (testTab != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Tab {testTab.TabLabel}: {testTab.Value}");
    } else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Tab not found.");
    }

    // RequestEnvelopeV2 Method
    var requestOptions = new RequestEnvelopeV2Options() {
        IncludeAC = false,
        IncludeAnchorTabLocations = true,
        IncludeDocumentBytes = false
    };
    var envelopeV2 = client.RequestEnvelopeV2(_envelopeId, requestOptions);
    var testTabV2 = envelopeV2.Tabs.FirstOrDefault(t => t.TabLabel.Contains("Test"));
    if (testTabV2 != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Tab(v2) {testTabV2.TabLabel}: {testTabV2.Value}");
    } else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Tab(v2) not found.");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\r\nDone.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Output:

```
Subject: Please DocuSign: Test Envelope
Tab txtDataLabelTest1: Some Data Here
Tab(v2) txtDataLabelTest1: Some Data Here

Done.
```